# TCL/Regex - Getting values from multiple lines

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

This is my output:

```
Signal Quality  = 100
Signal Strength = -49
Noise Level     = -96
```

I am trying to get all three numeric values (i.e., 100, -49, -96). I will be adding and subtracting these values, so I need each in its own variable?

These numbers are dynamic and could be a negative number.

Using the code below, I could grab one at the time, but how would a go about grabbing all 3 numbers?

```
expect {                    
    -re {Strength = +(.*)\s+Noise} {
        set RSSI $expect_out(1,string)
    }
    puts "Signal Strength = $RSSI"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all three values in the one `expect` call, you need a little trickiness.

```
# Initialize to an empty array
unset myAry
array set myAry {}

# Now let's expect some stuff!
expect {
    -re {(\w+)\s+=\s+(-?\d+)} {
        # Found it; stuff in an array
        set myAry($expect_out(1,string)) $expect_out(2,string)
        # TRICKY! Keep waiting if we've not yet got all three values
        if {[array size myAry] < 3} {
            exp_continue
        }
    }
}
```

With that output from the spawned process, that'll set `myAry(Quality)` to `100`, `myAry(Strength)` to `-49`, and `myAry(Level)` to `-96`. To use both words, use this as your pattern:

```
{(\w+\s+\w+)\s+=\s+(-?\d+)}
```

and then you'll probably want to strip the spaces:

```
set key [string map {{ } {}} $expect_out(1,string)]
set myAry($key) $expect_out(2,string)
# Now that optionally-keep-waiting stanza from above
```

That can, of course, be a one-liner. I just don't like my lines to be so long usually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about tcl regex's but something like this might work.
The numbers are in capture groups 1,2,3 in order.
Need Dot-All or add `(?s)` or change '`.`' to `[\S\s]`

```
 #  Quality\s*=\s*([+-]?\s*\d+)\s*.*?Strength\s*=\s*([+-]?\s*\d+).*?Level\s*=\s*([+-]?\s*\d+)


 Quality \s* = \s* 
 ( [+-]? \s* \d+ )              # (1)
 \s* 
 .*? 
 Strength \s* = \s* 
 ( [+-]? \s* \d+ )              # (2)
 .*? 
 Level \s* = \s* 
 ( [+-]? \s* \d+ )              # (3)
```